# Extension of a measure from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mathbb{R}$ be equipped with the standard Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R})$, that is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the open sets of $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose $\mu$ is a measure on $(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R}))$. I want to understand how to extend $\mu$ to the set $\bar{\mathbb{R}} = \mathbb{R}\cup \{+\infty\}$. By $\bar{\mathbb{R}} = \mathbb{R}\cup \{+\infty\}$ I mean the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}$, which is a compact topological space.

It is not clear to me how to make such extension. Some of my thoughts: first, I need to equip $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ with a suitable $\sigma$-algebra, say, $\mathcal{F}$. My guess would be to consider the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F} = \mathbb{B}(\bar{\mathbb{R}})$ generated by the open sets of $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$, that is, the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the set:
$$\tau_{\bar{\mathbb{R}}} = \tau_{\mathbb{R}} \cup \{U \cup \{+\infty\}: \text{$U \in \tau_{\mathbb{R}}$ and $U^{c} = \mathbb{R}\setminus U$ is compact}\}.$$
However, if this is the correct $\sigma$-algebra to equip $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$, how to exten $\mu$ to $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$? What I would like to do is, roughly speaking, set the "measure of infinity to zero". Something like: $\mu(E \cup \{+\infty\}) = \mu(E)$, for $E \in \mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R})$. However, it is not clear to me if all the sets $E$ of the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathbb{B}(\bar{\mathbb{R}})$ either elements of $\mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R})$ or elements of the form $E\cup \{+\infty\}$, so I can define the measure $\mu$ as I want. Any help is really apreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The embedding $e:\Bbb{R}\to\overline{\Bbb{R}}$ of a topological space to its one-point compactification is continuous.  Every continuous map is Borel (see [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Mapping_is_Measurable)).  For any Borel set $E\subseteq \overline{\Bbb{R}}$, $e^{-1}(E)=E\cap \Bbb{R}$ is Borel.  If $\infty\not\in E$ then $e^{-1}(E) = E$, and if $\infty\in E$ then $E = e^{-1}(E)\cup\{\infty\}$.

Answer (score 1):

What you wish to claim is true. To prove it, we need a construction of the $\sigma$-algebra on $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ based on ordinals.

Given a collection $\mathfrak{M}_0$ of subsets of a set $X$. Recursively construct $\mathfrak{M}_\alpha$ for all $\alpha<\omega_1$ in the following way (here $\omega_1$ is the least uncountable ordinal):

1. $\mathfrak{M}_{\alpha+1}$ is the collection of all countable unions and complements of members of $\mathfrak{M}_\alpha$;
2. if $\alpha$ is a nonzero limit ordinal, then $\mathfrak{M}_\alpha=\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha}\mathfrak{M}_\alpha$.

It's a good exercise on transfinite induction to show that $\mathfrak{M}=\bigcup_{\alpha<\omega_1}\mathfrak{M}_\alpha$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathfrak{M}_0$. Now let $\mathfrak{M}_0$ be the topology on $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$. Again, by transfinite induction it's not hard to see that every member of $\mathfrak{M}$ is either $E$ or $E\cup\{\infty\}$ for some $E\in\mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R})$.